# JavaScript: proper user of SJCL encryption in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, encryption

I'm using the [minified version](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/sjcl.js) of [SJCL](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/) to encrypt the backup files requested by the users. It is in a [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) add-on for Google Sheets.

I'm mostly concerned with correct use, exception handling and best practices of adding the encryption part in the script. It is currently working as expected in backup and in restore process.

### The Backup (and Encryption)

#### User enter passphrase

It starts by asking the user to enter and re-enter the passphrase in a prompt. 1) One concern here is that the text field of the prompt doesn't mask the passphrase. To fix that I would show a dialog with HTML and form (password input). But then I would need to work client-server call and, while that is not an issue, the prompt is much simpler, less complicated and it won't be necessary to put a HTML - that could be questionable by the user?

```
const passphrase1 = ui.prompt(
  'Backup',
  'Enter passphrase:',
  ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
if (passphrase1.getSelectedButton() === ui.Button.CANCEL) return 0;

const passphrase2 = ui.prompt(
  'Backup',
  'Please re-enter this passphrase:',
  ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
if (passphrase2.getSelectedButton() === ui.Button.CANCEL) return 0;
```

#### Test passphrase

Here, the script tests if the passphrases match, and it also tests passphrase length and if it has at least upper, lower, numbers and special characters. It is a very simple test - so `pA$$w0rd00` pass the test - and I actually didn't want to test anything like GnuPG does. In this case, is nothing (no test, like GnuPG) better than this simple test?

```
const passphrase = passphrase1.getResponseText();
if (passphrase !== passphrase2.getResponseText() || passphrase.length < 10 || testPassphrasePolicy(passphrase)) {
  ui.alert(
    'Backup',
    'Invalid passphrase.',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  return 1;
}

function testPassphrasePolicy (passphrase) {
  if (!/[a-z]+/.test(passphrase)) return 1;
  if (!/[A-Z]+/.test(passphrase)) return 1;
  if (!/[0-9]+/.test(passphrase)) return 1;
  if (!/[~!@#$%^*-_=+[{\]}/;:,.?]+/.test(passphrase)) return 1;

  return 0;
}
```

#### Encrypt data

The encryption part is pretty straight forward. The `backup`is a object like `backup = { foe: 'abc', bar: 123 }`. The steps are as follow:

1. Stringify `backup`
2. Encode to base64
3. Compute SHA256
4. Concatenate the base64 with `:` and the SHA256
5. Encrypt with AES-128 in GCM mode and using the SHA256 as authentication data. If there is an error, simply return and show a generic message error.
6. Test decryption. If there is an error, simply return and show a generic message error.
7. Return a blob of the encrypted backup

I suspect steps 3 and 4 are overdoing, but before the addition of encryption that is how the script was doing an simple integrity test (with SHA1).

```
function encryptBackup_ (backup, passphrase) {
  const string = JSON.stringify(backup);
  const webSafeCode = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(string, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);

  const sha = computeDigest('SHA_256', webSafeCode, 'UTF_8');
  const data = webSafeCode + ':' + sha;

  let encrypted = '';
  try {
    encrypted = sjcl.encrypt(passphrase, data, { mode: "gcm", adata: sha });
  } catch (err) {
    ConsoleLog.error(err);
    return 0;
  }

  try {
    const decrypted = sjcl.decrypt(passphrase, encrypted);
    const parts = decrypted.split(':');
    const test_sha = computeDigest('SHA_256', parts[0], 'UTF_8');

    if (test_sha !== parts[1]) throw new Error('digestBackup_(): Bad decryption.');
  } catch (err) {
    ConsoleLog.error(err);
    return 0;
  }

  const date = Utilities.formatDate(DATE_NOW, 'GMT', 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss');
  const name = 'data' + date + '.backup';
  const blob = Utilities.newBlob(encrypted, 'application/octet-stream', name);

  return blob;
}
```

### The Restore (and Decryption)

Once the user select a Drive `file`, the script requests the passphrase and tries to decrypt the file. This part is testing if it is possible to decrypt the file selected by the user.

The passphrase is being cached [in a cache instance scoped to the current user and script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service#getusercache) so the script can retrieve it later to actually decrypt the file and restore the data. The cache expires in 120 seconds (session), and once it is retrieved later, it is immediately removed.

```
const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
const passphrase = ui.prompt(
  'Restore',
  'Enter passphrase:',
  ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
if (passphrase.getSelectedButton() === ui.Button.CANCEL) return 0;

let decrypted = null;

try {
  decrypted = sjcl.decrypt(passphrase.getResponseText(), data);
} catch (err) {
  ConsoleLog.error(err);
  return 4;
}

const address = computeDigest(
  'SHA_1',
  file.getId() + SpreadsheetApp2.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(),
  'UTF_8');
CacheService2.put('user', address, 'string', passphrase.getResponseText(), 120);

const parts = decrypted.split(':');
const test_sha = computeDigest('SHA_256', parts[0], 'UTF_8');

if (test_sha !== parts[1]) return 4;

const string = base64DecodeWebSafe(parts[0], 'UTF_8');
return JSON.parse(string);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### User enter passphrase

Nobody uses an OS modal dialog prompts anymore. I'd suggest a web page specific modal box such as shown [here](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form). You need to click "new user" to have the box show up.

As for the naming, `passphrase1` and `passphrase1` seem to loose information, why not `passphrase` and `passphraseReentered` (or `reenteredPassprase`)? Now it seems like two different passwords to me.

### Test passphrase

You haven't clearly documented which policy is being checked, although that might be in the design documentation or left out for now. But things like policy should not have to be derived from source code. It would be pretty tricky to validate the source code if it is leading so you would not be able to discern bugs.

```
if (passphrase !== passphrase2.getResponseText() || passphrase.length < 10 || testPassphrasePolicy(passphrase)) {
```

You're doing too much here, and it shows. First of all, checking if the password was correctly reentered is separate from testing the password policy. If it is a different check then it should be handled separately.

This will quickly become apparent anyway when users start to complain that they first entered the password **twice** before you check that the password complies with the policy (d'Oh!).

I'd argue that a length requirement should be part of the password policy, which removes another equation from the `if`.

```
if (!/[a-z]+/.test(passphrase)) return 1;
```

No, no no. First of all, at least return `false` or something similar, not `0` or `1`. But shouldn't you indicate which test failed to the user?

After all these checks you perform `return 0` which would actually sounds negative to me. However, I haven't seen that it fails on specific characters. That might be fine, but I'd personally make sure that the password doesn't contain any weird characters, control characters and such.

### Encrypt data

> I suspect steps 3 and 4 are overdoing, but before the addition of encryption that is how the script was doing an simple integrity test (with SHA1).

It is overdoing it, and since you're being incompatible with the original anyway, I'd remove the SHA-256 computation (note the dash in SHA-256).

```
const webSafeCode = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(string, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
```

Why you would expand your plaintext by encoding it before encryption is beyond me, GCM handles binary just fine, thank you.

```
const sha = computeDigest('SHA_256', webSafeCode, 'UTF_8');
```

So what does this return so that you can put it at the end of a textual string? If it returns hexadecimals or base 64 then this should be made clear when looking at the call.

```
 let encrypted = '';
```

If you fail to assign you will hit `return 0` and otherwise the assignment is performed in the next statement. Don't assign empty strings, or zero or null when it is not required.

```
encrypted = sjcl.encrypt(passphrase, data, { mode: "gcm", adata: sha });
```

> JCL strengthens your passwords by a factor of 1000

Yeah, that *might* have been fine when PBKDF2, the password strengthening version was first created. Nowadays you'd want to hit a million at the least, and maybe increase the work factor later. Using (just) passwords for any encryption is tricky, unfortunately.

I'll not comment on the decryption part within the encryption function. I think it is overly cautious because on error I would not expect the code to hit `return blob` but since it is backup data...

```
 if (test_sha !== parts[1]) throw new Error('digestBackup_(): Bad decryption.');
```

But I will comment on badly copied code, we're not in `digestBackup` and errors already should contain a stacktrace, so there is no need to log it additionally.

```
const date = Utilities.formatDate(DATE_NOW, 'GMT', 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss');
const name = 'data' + date + '.backup';
```

A date in seconds and a filename that uses that date to distinguish backups. Even **if** this would never happen in reality, your unit / application testers are going to despise you. You need a better way of keeping blobs apart. Worse they may not catch it and you may overwrite a previous backup - current computers are fast, you can do a lot in a second, and maybe you want to backup before and after a process was executed.

Note that the encrypt function starting from the (unnecessary) SHA calculation up to the blob creation is completely ignorant of the data type. If you'd spit that out you can test the encryption / decryption separately. EDIT: On the other hand, you could use the file name as additional authenticated data (`adata`) so an attacker cannot get away with renaming the backups. Still, you could add that data as parameter to the function call.

### The Restore (and Decryption)

First of all, where is the `decryptBackup_` function? Always make your applications symmetric, even if the result is just a single line method. Imagine the future developer (i.e. you) searching for it. Now you suddenly mix UI code and the code doing the actual work as well.

```
return 4;
```

Warning, high octarine levels detected. Don't use magic numbers!

```
const address = computeDigest(
  'SHA_1',
  file.getId() + SpreadsheetApp2.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(),
  'UTF_8');
CacheService2.put('user', address, 'string', passphrase.getResponseText(), 120);
```

Excuse me, what does this do? In here? At all?

```
if (test_sha !== parts[1]) return 4;
```

Four! Goofy golf ball error!

I like that you thought about your passphrase caching and management. Key/secret management is very important in crypto.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your time! I really appreciate it as my script needs a review before I consider merging it to the main branch. I learned new stuff and while one or two issues - see below - won't be a problem in this specific case, I'll keep your explanation in mind in other occasions. My comments on each for each issue you pointed out is too long for this box. How can I respond properly to your answer - what do you suggest?

Comment: More boxes, handle one comment at a time. We can always move to chat if the comment section gets too long, we'll be notified automatically.

Comment: Some considerations: 1. the code from the question is running in the server-side. By the way, the add-on is for Google Sheets, so everything is running in the server-side, except for a button "back up now" and the passphrase prompts. 2. After encryption, the file is sent via email to the user - that is required to the owner of the spreadsheet and user of the add-on - since an owner of a spreadsheet can share with another user that has the add-on.

Comment: Now, all the following parts has the same response "Noted, will fix!": "_Now it seems like two different passwords to me._".... "_checking if the password was correctly reentered is separate from testing the password policy_".... "_at least return false or something similar, not 0 or 1._".... "_First of all, where is the decryptBackup_ function? Always make your applications symmetric_".... "_Don't assign empty strings, or zero or null when it is not required._".... "_your unit / application testers are going to despise you_" I don't have any testers actually.

Comment: "_Nobody uses an OS modal dialog prompts anymore._" To be more specific, it is using the [Apps Script prompt dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#prompt_dialogs); should I still replace it with a [custom dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs) to show up a box?

Comment: "_Test passphrase_" The "policy" is at least 10 characters long containing at least one of each: upper, lower, number, and special symbol. It isn't a real policy but rather a suggestion/guidelines for the user since enforcing a good policy - that doesn't allow things like `pA$$w0rd00` or `1234567Qr!` (example) - is difficult and I have no idea how to start - the add-on doesn't make third-party calls. That is why I considered an approach similar to GnuPG encryption where no warning is given - but that would require me to suppose the user will be careful to choose a good passphrase.

Comment: I would not suppose that, generally users choose pretty weak passwords (about 42 bits of entropy on average if I remember correctly - quite a long way from the 128 bits you'd like for encryption), and password based encryption is already pretty weak. As for the password box, I found [this little gem on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36225756/589259).

Comment: "_But shouldn't you indicate which test failed to the user?_" I'll see what I can do. The prompt dialog is similar to the GnuPG: shows a prompt, you enter a passphrase, then another prompt and re-enter passphrase. Unless you are suggest it should be a dynamic interface to show X's or Ok's for each test.

Comment: "_make sure that the password doesn't contain any weird characters, control characters and such_" The prompt dialog is in [sanbox mode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/sandbox-mode) by Google so that wouldn't be a concern? What weird characters? I'm allowing whitespaces - like GnuPG does, erm... is it bad?

Comment: "_Why you would expand your plaintext by encoding it before encryption is beyond me_" I did that as a safeguard for foreing characters; I did some research on base64, but since I couldn't find anything completely clear I left it that way - as "don't fix what is not broken".

"_So what does this return so that you can put it at the end of a textual string?_" Yes, it returns hexadecimals.

Comment: GCM operates on bytes. If they represent foreign characters is entirely inconsequential. What you are currently doing is to have binary, then encode it to text using base 64, and then use the ASCII encoding of those as binary input for the encryption routine...

Comment: 1/2 "_Excuse me, what does this do? In here? At all?_" I'm using the [CacheService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#putkey,-value,-expirationinseconds) to add a key/value to the cache with an expiration. The scope is `user`, the key is `address`, the value is `passphrase.getResponseText()` and the expiration is `120 (seconds)`. The passphrase is only cached after decryption succeeds. Now, the only issue - that I saw - here is how to choose the key.

Comment: 2/2 I'm using the SHA-1 of the concatenation of the spreadsheet ID with the Drive file ID because only a concatenation could be too large for a key. I'm combining both spreadsheet ID and file ID to be certain the script will get the value from the correct key. For example, if it was only file ID and the user decided to open a new spreadsheet, it would be possible to start the restore process by passing only the file ID. Now, if it was only the spreadsheet, it would be feasible to start the restore process without going throught (jump) the `select backup file from Drive` process.

Comment: "_I like that you thought about your passphrase caching and management. Key/secret management is very important in crypto._" Something you can enlight me here in this part is if there is any issue with the cache being managed in the server-side by Google. Or if it would be better to ask **again** the user for the passphrase. There is this balance between don't bother user too much/user can enter wrong passphrase.

Comment: As for 1/2 it's not so much that you're doing something there, but why isn't it at least in a well named method implementation and again, there is a problem with symmetry here. If you read the encryption function, then you don't expect this in the decryption function suddenly. I'd always at least indicate in a comment *what* is happening (how it is happening should be clear from the code).

Comment: 2/2 Great, you've got your method documentation right there :)